# Local JavaScript Files Not Updating - Stencil CLI

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I am modifying a purchased stencil-based theme for a client. When I modify javascript files, bundle.js does not update and I do not see a file change in the CLI. I am unable to see my changes on the local site. However, as a test, I was able to modify bundle.js directly and saw my change take place.

I have looked through the BC docs and have asked questions in other forums, but still no solution. I am not getting any errors in the CLI when I start stencil or run the bundle command. I can also upload my theme to the store without error.

Any ideas?

**Edit:

Here are the contents of my stencil.conf.js file:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.conf.js');

webpackConfig.context = __dirname;
webpackConfig.entry = path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/js/app.js');
webpackConfig.output = {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/js'),
  filename: 'bundle.js'
};

/**
 * Watch options for the core watcher
 * @type {{files: string[], ignored: string[]}}
 */
var watchOptions = {
  // If files in these directories change, reload the page.
  files: [
    '/assets',
    '/templates',
    '/lang'
  ],

  //Do not watch files in these directories
  ignored: [
    '/assets/scss',
    '/assets/css',
  ]
};

/**
 * Hook into the stencil-cli browsersync instance for rapid development of themes.
 * Watch any custom files and trigger a rebuild
 * @param {Object} Bs
 */
function development(Bs) {
  var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
  // Rebuild the bundle once at bootup
  compiler.watch({}, function(err, stats) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }

    Bs.reload();
  });
}

/**
 */
/**
 * Hook into the `stencil bundle` command and build your files before they are packaged as a .zip
 * Be sure to call the `done()` callback when finished
 * @param {function} done
 */
function production(done) {
  var compiler;

  webpackConfig.devtool = false;
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin());
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    comments: false
  }));

  compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

  compiler.run(function(err, stats) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    done();
  });
}

module.exports = {
  watchOptions: watchOptions,
  development: development,
  production: production,
};
```

Here are the contents of my webpack.conf.js file:

```
    var path = require('path');
    var webpack = require('webpack');

    module.exports = {
        devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map',
        bail: false,
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    loader: 'babel',
                    include: [
                        path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/js'),
                        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-utils'),
                    ],
                    query: {
                        compact: false,
                        cacheDirectory: true,
                        presets: [ ['es2015', {loose: true}] ]
                    }
                 }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [],
        watch: false
    };
```

Comment: Can you share your webpack config?  This should be in the stencil.conf.js and webpack.conf.js files in your theme's root directory.

Comment: @DonnyWest The question has been updated with the contents of stencil.conf.js and webpack.conf.js. Thanks for your time!

Comment: All looks good with your webpack config, are you sure the file you are editing is being imported into your entry file or one of its descendents?  Try making a change directly in the 'assets/js/app.js' file and see if that triggers a reload.  If it does, then your issue is probably related to the importing of the file(s) you were modifying.

Comment: @DonnyWest Modifying app.js does not trigger a reload. Also, I am only modifying js files that were already part of the theme at this point. I have not added any js files to the theme.

Comment: That's strange.  To confirm, you are able to run 'stencil start' in the theme's root directory, the command line prints out the local URL and some status messages, and you can successfully go to the local URL and see your development site running, correct?

Comment: @DonnyWest Yep, I can run stencil start and view everything locally with no issues.

Comment: That's odd, seems for all the world like it should be working.  I'd try uninstalling and reinstalling stencil-cli globally, deleting the node_modules directory inside of your theme, running npm cache clear and then reinstalling the theme's dependencies with npm i inside the theme directory.  That's as fresh of a start as you can get, perhaps that will shake loose whatever is acting up?

Comment: @DonnyWest I have now done the things you mentioned. My js files still don't seem to be updating, but modifying app.js now triggers a reload.

Comment: Nice, that's a step in the right direction at least, now we know that both stencil-cli and your theme's webpack config are working.  Again I'd double check to be sure that the file you want to modify is being imported into the bundle's entry point, and that it's not in one of the directories in the 'ignored' array in your webpack watch options (which seem to just be stylesheets, but it doesn't hurt to double check).  If the import isn't the culprit, try adding 'webpackConfig.cache = false;' at the top of your 'development' function in stencil.conf.js